# What does the $\ symbol mean in Python code?

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I find below code from a book to show how to use matplotlib in Python. The code runs normally. But I don't understand what does the symbol $ or $\ mean here?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
y = np.sin(x) + 1
z = np.cos(x**2) + 1

plt.figure(figsize = (8, 4))
plt.plot(x,y,label = '$\sin x+1$', color = 'red', linewidth = 2)
plt.plot(x, z, 'b--', label = '$\cos x^2+1$')
plt.xlabel('Time(s) ')
plt.ylabel('Volt')
plt.title('A Simple Example')
plt.ylim(0, 2.2)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: That's syntax specific to matplot, not Python. Likely Latex formula notation or such (not entirely sure, but the direction is correct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't mean anything in Python. `$` marks the beginning and end of maths in a LaTeX string.

`$\sin x+1$` means [image]

Similarly, `$\cos x^2+1$` will be [image]

For a basic tutorial in MathJax (which uses LaTeX syntax) [read this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

It represents a Latex-like syntax.

Example: `$X_y$`  <-- Latex for X with "y" as it's subscript.

It looks like this, when rendered:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually your question title is misleading.

`$...$` It is latex syntax for mathematical environment (as already mentioned above).

The backslash has nothing to do with the dollar sign, it is a LaTeX command, for example here for drawing `sin`

```
$\sin x+1$
```